# Inserting a line return in Excel VBscript / VBA

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Using Excel v16

I'm trying to format text in a cell by replacing a character like tilde ~ with a carriage return whereby the finished result would be multiple lines. This is actually a merged cell of multiple rows and columns as shown below

This is the input
[image]

This is the desired output
[image]

Here is the script I'm using in my macro

```
Sub FindReplaceAll()
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Range("A34").Select

    iStr = ActiveCell.Value

    For i = 1 To Len(iStr)
        If Mid(iStr, i, 1) = "~" Then
            rtStr = rtStr + vbCr
    Else
        rtStr = rtStr + Mid(iStr, i, 1)
    End If

    Next i

    ActiveCell.Value = rtStr

End Sub
```

Unfortunately all I get is same line with the tilde removed
The cell is formatted with the wrap text.  Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The entirety of your subroutine can be replaced with just a single line: `Sheets("template").Range("A34").Value = Replacc(Sheets("template").Range("A34").value, "~", chr(10))` That will set that cell's value to itself, but replacing the tildes with a carriage return. As mentioned in the answer below you can use `vbcrlf` for a carriage return/line feed or `chr(10) & chr(11)` if you want to split hairs.

Comment: Wow. Worked.  Post it as the answer so I can select it as best response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entirety of your subroutine can be replaced with just a single line:

```
sub findReplaceAll()
    Sheets("template").Range("A34").Value = Replace(Sheets("template").Range("A34").value, "~", chr(13)) 
end sub
```

That will set that cell's value to itself, but replacing the tildes with a carriage return. As mentioned in @johncoleman's answer you can use `vbcrlf` for a carriage return/line feed or `chr(13) & chr(10)` if you want to split hairs.

This could also be done in a worksheet formula with:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A34, "~", CHAR(13))
```

Comment: You have a typo, it's `Replace`, and it's `chr(13)` for a carriage return.

Comment: One typo I should have mentioned  = Replace  you have a double cc

Comment: Thanks both. Updated. I always get those chr() values backwards. Updated the answer fixing the REPLACC, swapped chr(10) with chr(13) so it's a carriage return instead of a line feed.

Answer (score 4):

In general, in Windows for [newlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) you would need `vbCrLF` rather than `vbCr`. Multiline strings can be written to an Excel cell using either `vbCrLf` or simply `vbLf`. Doing the later corresponds directly with what would happen if you enter such a string from the user interface using `Alt+Enter`.

Doing this potentially causes problems if you intend to do something else with the string other than display it in a cell, such as write it to a text file or copy it to the clipboard and paste it to a different application. For example, if in cell `A1` you type `a Alt+Enter b` you will see `a` displayed directly over `b`, but if you run the following code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim f As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = FSO.CreateTextFile("C:/programs/test.txt")
    f.Write Range("A1").Value
    f.Close
End Sub
```

and then inspect the file in Notepad, the line breaks won't display. For these sorts of reasons, I almost always use `vbCrLf` when building up multi-line strings in VBA.

Thus -- if you want to simply display the string use either `chr(10)` or `vbLf`, but it you might want to later use this string somewhere else, use `vbCrLf`.

Comment: Wrong. You need vbLf (Chr(10)) in Excel cells, that's also the character inserted when using the UI (Alt+Enter). vbCrLf works only because vbCr does nothing and vbLf does the job.

Comment: @z32a7ul This seems to be a general VBA strings  vs. Excel cell issue. For general purpose strings in VBA/VB6 and for things like Access VBA, you would use `vbCrLf` but you are correct that in Excel cells `vbLf` is enough. That is probably a space-optimization. It does seem to cause copying problems if you want to take such a multiline string in an excel file and write it in a text file, so I guess it depends partially on your purposes.

Comment: @z32a7ul By the way -- thanks for the correction. I edited my post to incorporate your point.